# Buscar elementos de una lista

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

Hola necesito buscar elementos de una lista, tengo una clase Cliente

```
 public class Cliente 
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    public EnumDocumentoEdentidad DocumentoIdentidad { get; set; }
    public string NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
    public string Direccion { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    public virtual  ICollection<Venta> Ventas  { get; set; }
}
```

Tengo controles en un formulario Windows Forms los cuales se llaman de la siguiente manera `txtClienteId`, `txtRazonSocial`, `txtDocumentoIdentidad`. Entonces lo que quiero buscar es lo siguiente:

Como verán los controles se llaman igual que las propiedades salvo que tienen al inicio txt, cbo, etc delante de ellos. necesito hacer una búsqueda en nombre del control si la propiedad se llama RazonSocial que busque en todos los controles `RazonSocial` y si lo encuentra ponerle el contenido de `txtRazonSocial` a la propiedad `RazonSocial`, en otras palabras asignarle el valor al atributo.

```
 public void Guardar(Form frm)
    {
        ObtenerValorControles(frm);
        List<ControlEntity> result = ObtenerNameControles(frm);

        Control obj = new Control();
        obj.GetAllControls();

        var controles = from b in frm.GetAllControls()
            where b is TextBox || b is ComboBox || b is CheckBox
            select b;

        if (nameForm == "Cliente")
        {
            var prop = new Cliente();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in prop.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.Name = result.Contains(prop))
                {

                }

            }
        }
```

Obtengo el nombre de los controles

```
 public List<ControlEntity> ObtenerNameControles(Form frm)
    {
        nameForm = Convert.ToString(frm.Tag);

        Control obj = new Control();
        obj.GetAllControls();

        var controles = from b in frm.GetAllControls()
            where b is TextBox || b is ComboBox || b is CheckBox || b is Form
            select b;

        foreach (var control in controles)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                nameCheck = ((CheckBox) control).Name;
            }
            if (control is ComboBox)
            {
                nameCombo = ((ComboBox) control).Name;
            }
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                nameTextBox = ((TextBox) control).Name;
            }


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameCheck))
            {
                var n = new ControlEntity() {Name = nameCheck};
                listNombreControles.Add(n);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameCombo))
            {
                var n = new ControlEntity() {Name = nameCombo};
                listNombreControles.Add(n);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameTextBox))
            {
                var n = new ControlEntity() {Name = nameTextBox};
                listNombreControles.Add(n);
            }
        }
        return listNombreControles();

    }
```

Comment: la verdad es que veo complejo hacer esto dinamico, otras implementaciones permiten establecer un mapping entre el control y los datos, lo que se conoce como binding

Comment: Siguiendo el comentario de @LeandroTuttini no entiendo la idea de hacer esto. con todo el codigo escrito a esta altura, y el overhead, se podia haber escrito o un binding o directamente cliente.nombre = txtnombre...

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de programarte un binding magico porque no usas lo existente, creo que en el tiempo que te llevara programar esto que planteas podria terminar el binding de todos los forms

[Entity Framework in WinForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221931/Entity-Framework-in-WinForms)

Si analizas el titulo **Creating a Form View (With an EntityBindingNavigator)** veras como realiza el `DataBinding` de las propiedades del modelo al control del form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Leandro, voy a revisar la liga que me brindas gracias por la informacion

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que el código se puede simplificar bastante aún usando reflexión, traté de alterar lo menos posible tu código para lograrlo en la forma que deseas.

```
public void Guardar(Form frm)
{
    ObtenerValorControles(frm);
    List<ControlEntity> result = ObtenerNameControles(frm);

    Control obj = new Control();
    obj.GetAllControls();

    var controles = from b in frm.GetAllControls()
        where b is TextBox || b is ComboBox || b is CheckBox
        select b;

    if (nameForm == "Cliente")
    {
        var prop = new Cliente();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in prop.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo.Name == result.Contains(prop))
            {
                var prop2 = GetControlByName(propertyInfo.Name).GetType().GetProperty("Text");//TODO:Agregar una relación para el tipo de campo
                    prop2?.SetValue(GetControlByName(propertyInfo.Name), cliente.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(cliente,null), null);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

En mi ejemplo tengo *hardcodeado* la propiedad Text, si quieres lo puedes extender y hacerlo más flexible.

Saludos

Comment: Hola @Ed García, gracias por el tiempo que le dedicastes lo voy a analizar